# json annotation to configure the serialized xml node's name of an object's property

Tags: java, xml, json

What i need to do is the following. i need using json, to serialize my object to xml as follows:

```
<employee>
   <name>Name</name>
   <id>the_database_id</id>
<employee>
```

my java code/bean is as follows:

```
public class PairPOJO<K,V> implements IPair<K,V> {
    private K first;
    private V second;
...
}
```

for reasons irrelevant for my problem, firtst/second need to remain with these names...

so the serialization produces

```
   <employee>
      <first>Name</first>
      <second>the_database_id</second>
   <employee>
```

I am new to json, is there any bean annotation or any other way letting me to accomplish what i need to do? any site, example, info is highly appreciated.

Comment: Eh?  You want to use JSON to serialize a java object to XML?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Show us your serialisation code. Are you converting the bean to json and then to xml?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use JSON? It's just a common data format and as such seems like an additional unnecessary translation to go from POJO->JSON->XML. Why not just go POJO->XML?

Comment: Also: which library/framework are you using? Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code snippet is...

```
import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;    
private String serializeItem(Object obj) {
    JSON jsonObject = JSONSerializer.toJSON(obj);
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsEnabled(true);
    return xmlSerializer.write(json);
}
```

> Eh? You want to use JSON to serialize a java object to XML? That makes no sense. – skaffman 2 hours ago

and

> Can you explain why you want to use JSON? It's just a common data format and as such seems like an additional unnecessary translation to go from POJO->JSON->XML. Why not just go POJO->XML?

Is there any better way for me to serialize to xml from complex objects? As i said it is the first time i need to do something similar and got over web that this is the best/better way to do it.

The general idea is that i need to return through REST ws beans.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
             <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
             <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
             <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: sorry for living this question open. I found the answer to my problem that what i was trying to do made no sence, as skaffman mentioned. Just forget this question as it was a tottaly 'stupid' one.